# Fetch discount start date and end date

Tags: commerce

I have a discount 'women's day'. I have set start and end date as 8March 8AM to 8 March 8PM for this discount. In my coupon validation function, I want to check if the current time is in between 'women's day' discount start and end time or not. So I basically need a start and end time of discount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don’t want to allow a coupons for specific time period, if discount is activated for specific period

1. Add a rule with event Redeem a coupon
2. Add a condition Data comparison to check site:current-date > start date (value)
3. Add a condition Data comparison to check site:current-date < end date (value)
4. Add an action to remove all the coupon
   5 Add an action to show msg on site

Comment: thanks Shrikant Nakade, resolving with this method is what agreed by others.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why do you need that..

From your question I can assume you have both the discount module and coupons module..

If using discount in general, you don't need to apply a coupon, and the discount will be applied with rules only on the dates that you put in on the default discount creation form.

The same goes for coupon creation, when creating a coupon, you can set coupon criteria as date range and that will also be applied by default in coupon validation.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to load the discount by using:

```
$discount = entity_load('commerce_discount', YOUR_DISCOUNT_ID);
```

To see what's available to you, install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and use the `dpm()` function:

```
$discount = entity_load('commerce_discount', YOUR_DISCOUNT_ID);
dpm($discount);
```

You can run this from the `/devel/php` page.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, mark this post as the "Answer" for others with the same question.